# Angular 2: How do I use angular animations to fade in/fade out of components within <router-outlet> after the initial load?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-animations

As of right now, the code is working as it should (but now how I want haha). The animation works and fades in when the page initially loads &  is first initialized but the animations do not occur when I am accessing routes within the  after the initial page fade in. Just wondering how I could implement my animation to each sibling route.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Below are my app component files where I wrote the animation. I then put the trigger into the HTML.

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    animations:[
        trigger('main-router', [
            state('in', style({
                opacity: 1
            })),
            transition('void => *', [
                style({opacity: 0}),
                animate(2000)
            ]),
            transition('* => void', [
                style({opacity: 0}),
                animate(2000)
            ])
        ])
    ]
})
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="router-outlet-outer" [@main-router] >
    <router-outlet>
    </router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following [blog entry](https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-router-animations) by Cory Rylan should answer all of your questions.

---

> On the router outlet, we create a template reference to the outlet directive with the template variable assignment #o="outlet". With this reference to the outlet directive, we can get the information of when the router outlet is active to trigger our fade animation.

```
<main [@fadeAnimation]="o.isActivated ? o.activatedRoute : ''">
   <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
</main>
```

https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-router-animations
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p2vuku